# RedirectMatch 301 change query string to folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I recently write url in my website via htaccess from query string to virtual folders and it's working nicely.
Because of SEO issues I need to redirect old pages to new virtual folder addresses.I am having trouble with redirecting pattern and I am desperated :(

I need to redirect url like **?page=artreader&id=56**  to **fa/56**

I am using this code in htaccess but its not working fine:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.+)page=artreader&id=(.+)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/fa/$2
```

I appreciate it if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?page=artreader&id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ fa/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^fa/([^/.]+)/?$ ?page=artreader&id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```